# App Store Server Notifications: How to get a price of a transaction?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to create statistics based on the price a subscription was purchased with or renewed with. I don't see such field anywhere in the App Store Server Notifications api.

Can somebody advise on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to get the price of a transaction with App Store Server Notifications or via the [the JSON data returned in the response from the App Store.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody)

What you can do is get the ID of the transaction and look for it in the Sales & Trends dashboard. The easiest way to create statistics for your app is likely to have a separate database that stores transactions sent via your application through custom POST methods. What you're trying to do is not what the [App Store Server Notifications API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications) was built for, so you will run into problems. Specifically, their documentation says "Use the data in the notifications to update your user-account database, and to monitor and respond to in-app purchase refunds." Thus; this API was built for sales and customer support, not statistics and trends.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I get your point.

Is there a way to request current subscription price give productId? I'm trying to get it from App Store Connect, but don't see an option like this there.

Comment: @MaciejCaputa Unfortunately that isn't available; like I said you can store those values on your own database and manage analytics from there.